# AttributeError list object has no attribute add

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Python is new for me and I am doing some machine learning code using python. My scenario is that I am reading data from my sql and trying to give a shape to this data so i can use it for MLP training.

My code is below:

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='mysql', db='medicalgame')

cur = connection.cursor()
query = ""
cur.execute(query)
# X_train will be a list of list and later we'll convert it to a numpy ndarray
X_train = []

for row in cur:
    X_train.add(row)
connection.close()

X_train should be ready
X_train = np.asarray(X_train)
print 'The shape of X_train is', X_train.shape
```

During debug the query result i got is like this: 
(6, 1, 1, 1, 2, u'F', 1, 0, 0, 19)
Can anyone help me how can, I fix the error and give shape to my X_train, so that MLP accept it as an input ?

Comment: use `append`, `add` is for sets.

Comment: can you explain the problem about the query? you mean you get rows but sometimes a letter slips in and you'd like to remove it?

Comment: Looks like for now append works but i am not sure why this strange letter 'u' is coming in my query result. 
my X_train is like this now :
[(6, 1, 1, 1, 2, u'F', 1, 0, 0, 19), (6, 1, 1, 1, 2, u'V', 1, 0, 0, 14)]
can you tell me how can i remove this '(' with  '[' this ?

Comment: `u'F'` is a unicode character. Presumably your data base has a character or string valued field.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the message is clear. `list` has no method `add` because it is *ordered* (it has a dunder `__add__` method but that's for addition *between lists*). You can `insert` but you want to `append`. So the correct way is:

```
X_train = []

for row in cur:
    X_train.append(row)
```

BUT the preferred way converting to a list directly (iterating on `cur` elements to create your list in a simple and performant way):

```
X_train = list(cur)
```

BUT you cannot do that since your list contains bogus data. Fortunately, you can filter them out in a nested list comprehension like this:

```
X_train = [[x for x in r if type(x)==int] for r in cur]
```

this builds your list of lists but filters out non-integer values and feeding it to `numpy.asarray` yields (with your sample data):

```
[[ 6  1  1  1  2  1  0  0 19]
 [ 6  1  1  1  2  1  0  0 14]]
```

Comment: Thank you jean your answer is perfect and helps me make my dataset correctly

Comment: that's good! but I would investigate on that bogus entry if I were you. If you don't know why it's here, you may have more problems in the future.

Comment: that bogus entry is to identify me that the string value is unicode :) .. I fixed it using this 
X_train[X_train == 'F'] == 0
Because for my MLP i need only numeric data.

Comment: in which case you can just do `X_train = list(cur)`

Comment: you mean i dont need for loop if i used this     X_train = list(cur) ?

Comment: you don't need `[[x for x in r if type(x)==int] for r in cur]` if you fix your database. But I'm not sure.

Comment: How come `dir(list)` pulls up `add` also?

Comment: Must be `__add__`. Not the same thing.